# Tracking Duration of Mouse Event

Tags: swift, macos, appkit, nsevent

Is there a way to track the time between a mouseDown and a mouseUp event in swift? Or would one have to implement their own tracker manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the [`NSEvent.timestamp`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1528239-timestamp), which is a `TimeInterval` (typealias for `Double`, storing number of seconds):

```
let duration = mouseUpEvent.timestamp - mouseDownEvent.timestamp
```